# segmentation fault when using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I was keeping getting the segmentation fault when call c++ from python using ctypes. i have attached the gdb to the c++ code and make sure that the C++ code works well. The segmentation fault was raised after the c++ code has correct return value and before returning to the python code. i checked everything else i guess might be a mistake, especially the in/out parameters, but still couldn't get any clue of where is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is the c++ code:

### string_utils.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

using namespace std;

class SimpleTrieNode {
public:
    char key = '\0';
    bool end = false;
    unsigned int num_children = 0;
    SimpleTrieNode* p_next_sibling = nullptr;
    SimpleTrieNode* p_first_child = nullptr;

public:
    SimpleTrieNode* add_child(char key) {
        if (p_first_child == nullptr) {
            p_first_child = new SimpleTrieNode();
            p_first_child->key = key;
            num_children++;
            return p_first_child;
        }
        SimpleTrieNode *p = p_first_child, *p_prev;
        while (p != nullptr) {
            if (p->key == key) {
                return p;
            }
            p_prev = p;
            p = p->p_next_sibling;
        }
        p = new SimpleTrieNode();
        p_prev->p_next_sibling = p;
        p->key = key;
        num_children++;
        return p;
    }

    SimpleTrieNode* get_child(char key) {
        SimpleTrieNode *p = p_first_child;
        while (p != nullptr) {
            if (p->key == key) {
                return p;
            }
            p = p->p_next_sibling;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    ~SimpleTrieNode() {
        SimpleTrieNode *p = p_first_child, *p_next = nullptr;
        while (p != nullptr) {
            p_next = p->p_next_sibling;
            delete p;
            p = p_next;
        }
    }
};

class SimpleTrie {
public:
    SimpleTrieNode root;
    unsigned int max_len = 0;

public:
    SimpleTrieNode* add(char* d) {
        string data(d);
        if (max_len < data.length()) {
            max_len = data.length();
        }
        SimpleTrieNode* p = &root;
        for (char c : data) {
            p = p->add_child(c);
        }
        p->end = true;
        return p;
    }

    bool exist(string q) {
        SimpleTrieNode* p = &root;
        for (char c : q) {
            if (p != nullptr) {
                p = p->get_child(c);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
};

unsigned int convert_2d_index_to_1d(unsigned int i, unsigned int j,
        unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    return i * x + j;
}

_Bool compute_edit_distance_by_diagonal(SimpleTrieNode const * const p_node,
        string q, unsigned int len_x, unsigned int len_y, unsigned int i,
        unsigned int j, unsigned int threshold, unsigned int matrix[],
        char matched_seq[]) {
    unsigned int k = j;
    unsigned int min_row_value = threshold + 1;
    matched_seq[i - 1] = p_node->key;
    matched_seq[i]='\0';
    while ((j - i <= threshold || j < i) && j <= q.length()) {
        unsigned int min_dist = min(
                min(
                        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(i - 1, j, len_x + 1,
                                len_y + 1)] + 1,
                        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(i, j - 1, len_x + 1,
                                len_y + 1)] + 1),
                p_node->key == q[j - 1] ?
                        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(i - 1, j - 1, len_x + 1,
                                len_y + 1)] :
                        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(i - 1, j - 1, len_x + 1,
                                len_y + 1)] + 1);
        min_row_value = min(min_dist, min_row_value);
        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(i, j, len_x + 1, len_y + 1)] = min_dist;
        if (p_node->end && q.length() == j && min_dist <= threshold) {
            return true;
        }
        j++;
    }

    if (min_row_value > threshold || i >= threshold + len_y) {
        return false;
    }
    SimpleTrieNode *child = p_node->p_first_child;
    k = i < threshold + 1 ? k : k + 1;
    while (child != nullptr) {
        _Bool matched = compute_edit_distance_by_diagonal(child, q, len_x, len_y,
                i + 1, k, threshold, matrix, matched_seq);
        if (matched) {
            return matched;
        }
        child = child->p_next_sibling;
    }
    return false;
}

_Bool compute_edit_distance_by_diagonal(SimpleTrieNode const * const p_node,
        string q, unsigned int len_x, unsigned int len_y, unsigned int i,
        unsigned int j, unsigned int threshold, char matched_seq[]) {
    unsigned int size = (len_x + 1) * (len_y + 1);
    unsigned int matrix[size];
    fill_n(matrix, size, threshold+1);
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii <= threshold && ii < len_x + 1; ii++) {
        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(ii, 0, len_x + 1, len_y + 1)] = ii;
    }
    for (unsigned int jj = 0; jj <= threshold && jj < len_y + 1; jj++) {
        matrix[convert_2d_index_to_1d(0, jj, len_x + 1, len_y + 1)] = jj;
    }
    return compute_edit_distance_by_diagonal(p_node, q, len_x, len_y, i, j,
            threshold, matrix, matched_seq);
}

_Bool approximate_string_match(const SimpleTrie* p_trie, char* q,
        unsigned int threshold, char matched_seq[]) {
    string query(q);
    unsigned int qlen = query.length();

    SimpleTrieNode* child = p_trie->root.p_first_child;
    while (child != nullptr) {
        _Bool m = compute_edit_distance_by_diagonal(child, query,
                p_trie->max_len, qlen, 1, 1, threshold, matched_seq);
        if (m) {
            return m;
        }
        child = child->p_next_sibling;
    }
    return false;
}

extern "C" {
    SimpleTrie* SimpleTrie_Initialization() {
        SimpleTrie *p = new SimpleTrie();
        return p;
    }
    void SimpleTrie_Destruction(SimpleTrie *p) {
        delete p;
    }
    void SimpleTrie_Add(SimpleTrie *p,char *q) {
        p->add(q);
    }
    _Bool SimpleTrie_Approximate_string_match(SimpleTrie* p_trie, char *q,
            unsigned int threshold, char matched_seq[]) {
        return approximate_string_match(p_trie, q, threshold, matched_seq);
    }
}
```

Here is the makefile:

```
all:string_utils.so
string_utils.so: string_utils.cpp
    g++ -c -fPIC string_utils.cpp -o string_utils.o
    g++ -shared -Wall -o string_utils.1.0.so string_utils.o
    rm string_utils.o
```

Here is the python code:

### string_utils.py

```
from ctypes import *
import os
import codecs


lib_path = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
    'string_utils.1.0.so')
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
lib.SimpleTrie_Initialization.argtypes = []
lib.SimpleTrie_Initialization.restype = c_void_p
lib.SimpleTrie_Destruction.argtypes = [c_void_p]
lib.SimpleTrie_Destruction.restype = None
lib.SimpleTrie_Add.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]
lib.SimpleTrie_Add.restype = None
lib.SimpleTrie_Approximate_string_match.argtypes = [
    c_void_p,
    c_char_p,
    c_uint,
    c_char_p]
lib.SimpleTrie_Approximate_string_match.restype = c_bool


class SimpleTrie(object):
    initialized = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.SimpleTrie_Initialization()

    def __del__(self):
        lib.SimpleTrie_Destruction(self.obj)

    def add(self, q):
        lib.SimpleTrie_Add(self.obj, q.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

    def approximate_string_match(self, q, threshold):
        bs = q.encode(encoding='utf-8')
        matched_seq=create_string_buffer(len(bs)+threshold+1)
        m = lib.SimpleTrie_Approximate_string_match(self.obj, bs,
                                                    threshold, matched_seq)
        return m, matched_seq.value.decode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ptrie = SimpleTrie()
    lines = ['abderqwerwqerqweefg',
             'dfaewqrwqerwqerqwerqwerdfa',
             'afdfertewtertetrewqrwqrffg',
             'fgfdhgadsfsadfsadfadsffdhdf',
             'fgfdhgadsfsadjhgfdfadsffdhdf',
             'antihsadsfasdfaddafsadfsadsfasdaive',
             'dsgffdshgdsgffdadsfsadfsadfsfdasdfasdfasdfasdfsg'
             ]
    for line in lines:
        ptrie.add(line)
    x ,y = ptrie.approximate_string_match(u"antihsadsfasdfadsfasdaive", 6)
    print(x)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Learn how to attach gdb (a debugger) to your process/program to see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, i attached the gdb to the cpp code and have confirmed it  works as expected. the segmentation fault is raised after the cpp function returning correct value. I have updated the question.

Comment: segmentation fault **where**?  What line?  Provide the minimum, *complete* code to reproduce the issue.  This code doesn't compile.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: When you `add(line)`, the implementation makes a temporary encoding `q.encode(encoding='utf-8')` of the line.  Do you make a copy inside the C++ code?  If you just store the pointer, that byte string no longer exists after `add` returns.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for replying and pointing this. I have updated the question to include the full code.  As for the add(line), i make its own space by invoking new SimpleTrieNode()

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not relate to ctypes. There is a mess in cpp. This

```
unsigned int matrix[size];
```

cause stackoverflow… welcome. You are trying to put a large portion of data to stack. You should use `std::vector<unsigned>`, `std::unique_ptr<unsigned[]>` or other heap or static storages. 
Btw, it's not portable to use non-compile-time constants for array size.

Then you correct the memory allocation, it will fail somewhere further in recursion, because you pass strings by copying. You, probably, should use `const string& q` instead `string q`.

Comment: The VLA could well be causing the problem if the Python binding doesn't understand GCC's extension. _Code to standards only_

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit , I actually compiled c++ test. It fails without python. Python may not understand, but it does not matter until c++ errors are not fixed.

Comment: Okay then fair enough. Though I would still avoid extensions.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento. Thanks for the comment. But actually the matrix[size] is not the problem, because the size is not so big. The problem is "unsigned int size = (len_x + 1) * (len_y + 1); ", which should be "unsigned int size = (len_x + 1) * (len_y + 1+ threshold);"